# Server Eventlog warnings

Tags: .net, event-log

HI,

I am getting below warning messages. I dono why? But in my local its working great. No warnings in my machine eventlogs. Can anyone help me??? Here is my eventlog warnings..

> ```
> Log Name:      Application Source:        ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 Date:
> ```
>
> 2/11/2011 9:54:46 AM Event ID:
>   1309 Task Category: Web Event Level:
>   Warning Keywords:      Classic User:
>   N/A Computer:
>   PACDCPCCOMA01.cable.comcast.com
>   Description: Event code: 3005  Event
>   message: An unhandled exception has
>   occurred.  Event time: 2/11/2011
>   9:54:46 AM  Event time (UTC):
>   2/11/2011 2:54:46 PM  Event ID:
>   b60b4cc9c1c941a59414965489a83629 
>   Event sequence: 79355  Event
>   occurrence: 1  Event detail code: 0
>   Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-129418968817826366 
>       Trust level: Full 
>       Application Virtual Path: / 
>       Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\ 
>       Machine name: PACDCPCCOMA01    Process information: 
>       Process ID: 3912 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool    Exception information:
>
> ```
> Exception type: NullReferenceException 
> Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> ```
>
> object.    Request information: 
>       Request URL: http://ccom/EditWinAttachments.aspx?id=1
>
> ```
> Request path: /EditWinAttachments.aspx 
> User host address: 10.163.26.31 
> User: CABLE\HAlmei001 
> Is authenticated: True 
> Authentication Type: Negotiate 
> Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool    Thread
> ```
>
> information: 
>       Thread ID: 4 
>       Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool 
>       Is impersonating: False 
>       Stack trace:    at EditWinAttachments.gvAtt_ItemDataBound(Object
>   sender, GridItemEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\bpucha1103c\Desktop\Latest
>   code\CCOM_PROD\CellBackHaul\EditWinAttachments.aspx.cs:line
>   113    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.OnItemDataBound(GridItemEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridItem.SetupItem(Boolean
>   dataBind, Object dataItem,
>   GridColumn[] columns,
>   ControlCollection rows)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemBuilder.InitializeItem(Int32
>   dataSourceIndex, String&
>   nextItemHierarchicalIndex, Boolean&
>   itemIsInEditMode)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemBuilder.CreateItems(GridGroupingContext
>   group)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.CreateItems(IEnumerator
>   enumerator, GridColumn[] columns,
>   ControlCollection controls)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean
>   useDataSource)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean useDataSource)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data)    at
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments,
>   DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>   at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformSelect()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
>   at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.DataBind()
>   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.DataBind()
>   at EditWinAttachments.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents
>   and
>   Settings\bpucha1103c\Desktop\Latest
>   code\CCOM_PROD\CellBackHaul\EditWinAttachments.aspx.cs:line
>   39    at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>   at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>       Custom event details:
>
> Event Xml: 
>   
>       
>       1309
>       3
>       3
>       0x80000000000000
>       
>       9041
>       Application
>       PACDCPCCOMA01.cable.comcast.com
>             
>       3005
>       An unhandled exception has occurred.
>       2/11/2011 9:54:46 AM
>       2/11/2011 2:54:46 PM
>       b60b4cc9c1c941a59414965489a83629
>       79355
>       1
>       0
>       /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-129418968817826366
>       Full
>       /
>       C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\
>       PACDCPCCOMA01
>       
>       
>       3912
>       w3wp.exe
>       IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool
>       NullReferenceException
>       Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>       http://ccom/EditWinAttachments.aspx?id=1
>       /EditWinAttachments.aspx
>       10.163.26.31
>       CABLE\HAlmei001
>       True
>       Negotiate
>       IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool
>       4
>       IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool
>       False
>          at EditWinAttachments.gvAtt_ItemDataBound(Object
>   sender, GridItemEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\bpucha1103c\Desktop\Latest
>   code\CCOM_PROD\CellBackHaul\EditWinAttachments.aspx.cs:line
>   113    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.OnItemDataBound(GridItemEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridItem.SetupItem(Boolean
>   dataBind, Object dataItem,
>   GridColumn[] columns,
>   ControlCollection rows)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemBuilder.InitializeItem(Int32
>   dataSourceIndex, String&
>   nextItemHierarchicalIndex,
>   Boolean& itemIsInEditMode)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemBuilder.CreateItems(GridGroupingContext
>   group)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.CreateItems(IEnumerator
>   enumerator, GridColumn[] columns,
>   ControlCollection controls)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean
>   useDataSource)    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean useDataSource)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data)    at
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments,
>   DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>   at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformSelect()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
>   at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.DataBind()
>   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.DataBind()
>   at EditWinAttachments.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents
>   and
>   Settings\bpucha1103c\Desktop\Latest
>   code\CCOM_PROD\CellBackHaul\EditWinAttachments.aspx.cs:line
>   39    at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>   at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString[0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                gvAtt.ClientSettings.Scrolling.ScrollHeight = Unit.Pixel(400);
            }
        }
        lblMsg.Text = "";
        if (Session["selorderID"] != null)
        {
            DBLayer obj = new DBLayer();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@forderId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
            param.Value = Session["selorderID"].ToString();
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            DataSet dsGetAtt = obj.ExecuteDatasetSql("[usp_GetOrderAttachments]", cmd);
            gvAtt.DataSource = dsGetAtt;
            gvAtt.DataBind();
            //Session["RGAtt"] = dsGetAtt;
        }

        clsTaskUpdates_BL objBL = new clsTaskUpdates_BL();
        ddlAttCat.DataSource = objBL.getAttCate_BL();
        ddlAttCat.DataTextField = "Desc";
        ddlAttCat.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddlAttCat.DataBind();
        ListItem lst = new ListItem("Please Select", "0");
        ddlAttCat.Items.Insert(0, lst);

        ddlAttLvl.DataSource = objBL.getAttLvl_BL();
        ddlAttLvl.DataTextField = "Desc";
        ddlAttLvl.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddlAttLvl.DataBind();
        ListItem list = new ListItem("", "0");
        ddlAttLvl.Items.Insert(0, list);
        ddlAttLvl.Items.FindByText("ORDER").Selected = true;
    }

}

protected void gvAtt_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "AttaPath")
    {
        GridDataItem dataitem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        string strPath = dataitem["AttachmentPath"].Text.Trim();

        System.IO.FileInfo targetFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(strPath);
        if (targetFile.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(targetFile.FullName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            clsTaskUpdates_BL objBL = new clsTaskUpdates_BL();

            gvAtt.DataSource = objBL.getAttachments_Bl(Session["selorderID"].ToString());
            gvAtt.DataBind();
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.upEditWinAddAtt, this.GetType(), "strSear", "alert('The requested attachment is moved/ deleted. Click [OK] to refresh attachments.')", true);
        }
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        GridDataItem dataitem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        string strPath = dataitem["AttachmentPath"].Text.Trim();

        LinkButton lnkAttchName = (LinkButton)dataitem.FindControl("lblAttBy");
        string strAttachName = lnkAttchName.Text.Trim();
        string strAttchLevel = dataitem["AttachmentLevel"].Text.Trim();

        System.IO.FileInfo targetFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(strPath);
        if (targetFile.Exists)
            targetFile.Delete();
        clsTaskUpdates_BL objBL = new clsTaskUpdates_BL();

        gvAtt.DataSource = objBL.delAttachment_Bl(dataitem["oaId"].Text, Session["selorderID"].ToString(), strAttachName, strAttchLevel);
        gvAtt.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gvAtt_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            Label lblUser = (Label)dataItem.FindControl("lblCreatedBy");
            if (lblUser.Text.ToLower() != Session["UserName"].ToString().ToLower())
            {
                ImageButton imgDel = (ImageButton)dataItem.FindControl("lblDel");
                imgDel.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

protected void btnSaveAtt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lblMsg.Text = string.Empty;
        if (ddlAttLvl.SelectedItem.Value == "2" && Session["selProjectName"] == null)
        {
            //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "cls1", "<script>ErrMsg()</script>");
            lblMsg.Text = "Project Name is NULL, attachments can not be assigned at PROJECT Level. Please use ORDER Level to add attachments";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "";
            if (RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                UploadedFile file = RadUpload1.UploadedFiles[0];
                string targetFileName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttachmentPath"].ToString() + Session["selorderID"].ToString() + "-" + ddlAttCat.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss") + "-" + file.GetNameWithoutExtension() + file.GetExtension();
                file.SaveAs(targetFileName);
                clsTaskUpdates_BL objBL = new clsTaskUpdates_BL();
                gvAtt.DataSource = objBL.setAttachments_Bl(Session["selorderID"].ToString(), ddlAttCat.SelectedItem.Value, file.GetName(), targetFileName, ddlAttLvl.SelectedItem.Text);
                gvAtt.DataBind();
                //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "cls", "<script>parent.ref()</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "* Please select a file to attach.";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `EditWinAttachments.aspx` there is a variable that is `null` which should not be null. If you show some details about what you do in `EditWinAttachments.aspx` it might be easier to point down exactly on what the problem is.

I see that you are using a Grid View from Telerik, are you sure that the `DataSource` is not null when you try to `DataBind()` ?

Comment: Here is my sample code.... if there is any null then why it is not throwing an error... here is my code above please look at it...

Comment: When exactly are you getting the error? If you debug the application ,can you step through each method without errors?